# Android emulator not showing the running app

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am building and android application using Nativescript. After about a month of not touching the project i am trying now to run it again but facing a big problem - although from the visual code everything seems fine (i run command "tns run android" and everything looks good) i cant see the actual app on the android studio emulator. the emulator does gets turned on and the app gets installed on it but nothing happens next. the app will not start and there is no actual connection between the IDE and the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check please
Maybe it help you!

```
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5069
```

Comment: well i am not sure what was the problem. I tried to modify the environment variable like suggested in your solution but it didn't helped. eventually i just reinstalled android studio